# Find first CSS class on page

Tags: css

I have a page full of elements. I simply just want to match the first element in my CSS selector.

I have tried `sibling selector`, `first-child` and `first-of-type` but they all only work in a structure where there are siblings. In my case I have different depths which makes it harder.

```css
.match ~ .match {
  background:red;
}

.match:first-child {
  background: green;
}

.match:first-of-type {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>List item</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <div class="match">Match - First match should be red</div>
  </div>
  <div class="match">Match</div>
  <button></button>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="match">Match</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should find the first element with the class `.match`.

I will not accept answers like `div > div > .match` because then it does not find the element because we tell it where to look.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just CSS. I think you'd have to use JS to do this.

Comment: why not use an id or a second class? I think with only CSS selecting one class is hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible with pure CSS. If the HTML is static, you can add an ID or another class, as Snake_py suggested. If you're okay with using a script, the `document.querySelector` method returns the first match of the selector, so you could do something like this: (see snippet)

```js
document.querySelector('.match').classList.add('match-active')
```

```css
.match-active {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>List item</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <div class="match">Match - First match should be red</div>
  </div>
  <div class="match">Match</div>
  <button></button>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="match">Match</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to be the only way. I added classes with a script to each group. My final CSS then looks like this: `div:not(.task-group-0) > .task-group-item .task-type-headline { Something }`